# Python Selenium selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a little Problem with Python and selenium. But firstly i want to describe my Goals, I want to build a automatic login for a website, but it doesnt work. The error code

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

is everytime showed

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get ('website_name')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_login"]').send_keys('fakeemail')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_password"]').send_keys('fakepassword1')
```

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: I already tryed to used finde element by name and also by id but these doesnt work to.